# Launch an application inside a sandbox

Tags: windows, events, language-agnostic, overlay

Is there any way to launch a Win application inside a sandbox, so that i can capture TCP and UDP packets, system events, and draw function calls?

I would like to create an game overlay. The only necessary thing I need is getting the applications blitting surface, so i could then draw what the application draws, as well as my new elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that "sandbox" is the most common parlance for what you're looking for. Perhaps what you want is to *hook* the Windows API. This is a pretty complex subject. Knowing this terminology may help you find the right resources. For example, [API hooking revealed](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2082/API-hooking-revealed) looks like a very helpful article on the subject.

Comment: just a quick follow up question, since all apps look first in the working dir for libs, could i have libs with the same names, that notify me of their call, and call the real lib, or will there be a name conflict?

Comment: If the libs are .NET assembly DLLs, it depends on whether assembly signing was used. I haven't done native Windows code in a long time, but I don't think there'd be a conflict. Maybe someone else can chime in. Sounds like a good separate question to post.